# Клиент-серверное решение взаимодействия между EJB и Web-страницей

Tags: jpa, веб-программирование, java, ejb

Здравствуйте.
При проектировании `Web`-приложения с бизнес-логикой, реализованной на `EJB3.1 и JPA2`, *необходим* еще и *удобный* `MVC`-фреймворк или что-то очень практичное. 
**Вопрос:**
*Подойдет* ли `Spring3`,  т.е. сработается и срастется ли он с `EJB`? Или есть более **красивые** решения. Если есть, то какие? Может, в `EJB` есть что-то хорошее, реализующее `MVC` либо что-то удобное?
Меня по большей части волнует использование таких удобных штук `EJB`, как `Stateful Session Bean` и т.д. 
Или *лучшим* решением будет использование *сервлетов*, т.к. они позволят пользоваться всей мощью `EJB`?

Comment: Может, лучше использовать Servlet 3.0, EJB3.1, JPA2 и больше ничего?

Comment: К сожалению, универсального решения в таких делах не бывает. Я очень долго время жил без Spring'а и не жаловался и выходило неплохо. Spring даёт определённые преимущества, но ничто не мешает делать вам всё то же самое, только без него.

Comment: еще есть Java Server Faces, они как раз подразумеваются как MVC-фреймворк для EJB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Или лучшим решением будет использование сервлетов" - вам от них всё равно никуда не деться.

Мы, например, в своём достаточно большом проекте используем и EJB, и Spring и ещё много чего и всё прекрасно срастается и получается достаточно аккуратно.

Comment: Если у Вас есть в этом какой-то опыт, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать @Stateless в EJB и использовать его посредством Spring MVC. К примеру, Hello Word!.Просто что-то документации по этому поводу маловато нашел и все сухо описано. Короче, ничего не понял.

Comment: И, если можно, необходимые XML-файлы и их содержание.

Answer (score 0):

Я предалгаю использовать либо jsp\jsf+PrimeFaces,  что позволит быстро и красиво нарисовать веб, либо правильно - это REST слой с вебом на javascrip+jquery+++куча всего с общением через json. но тут нужен веб разработчик.